# Multiple JARs in APPCPATH

Tags: windows, jar, batch-file

I need to specify multiple jars in the appcpath of my .bat file.
Suppose i want to add two jars: a.jar, b.jar.

I specify:

```
SET A=a.jar
SET B=b.jar
SET APPCPATH=%A%;%B%
```

But this doesn't work (i receive a null pointer exception that shows how objects from b.jar are not imported in the APPCPATH).

Other info:
If i only specify

```
SET APPCPATH=%A%
```

it works.

While if i specify

```
SET APPCPATH=%A%;%B%
```

only objects from a.jar are loaded.

So, i think adding ";" between two jar isn't the right way. Couldn't find anything on Google...
Anyone knows how to specify multiple jars?

Answer (score 0):

from [this](http://vlad-mi.livejournal.com/566.html), it looks like the separator is the colon `:`